# mdk3 beacon pwning not detected by other devices

Tags: wifi, wireless

I'm new to wireless security. I'm trying to pwn beacon frames to announce a new access point using mdk3. However, when I run the command I get the following result where the MAC address is not changing and the AP is not detected by any device.

```
> mdk3 wlan0mon b -n SSID     
Current MAC: 00:9E:18:79:FE:7F on Channel  2 with SSID: Pwned  
Current MAC: 2F:00:00:00:00:00 on Channel  5 with SSID: Pwned  
Current MAC: 2F:00:00:00:00:00 on Channel  4 with SSID: Pwned  
Current MAC: 2F:00:00:00:00:00 on Channel  2 with SSID: Pwned
```

I have an atheros AR9271 usb wireless card and I run Kali linux on VMware.